# Extract object files from the archive that is generated by the Go compiler

Tags: go, binary, objdump, object-files, go-toolchain

I would like to analyse Go object files.

When I use the following command:

```bash
go tool compile -o test.o test.go
```

the generated file `test.o` is in the form of an archive (known as Go object archive).
I can extract it using

```bash
go tool pack x test.o
```

which extracts two files: `_go_.o` and `__.PKGDEF`
The `file` command outputs that those two are data files.

My problem is that the extracted object file is not in ELF format, so it can't be used by tools like `readelf` or `objdump`.
However go tools understand those files. For example I can disassemble it using:

```bash
go tool objdump _go_.o
```

Is there an other way to extract object files from go archives?
Or another way to compile go code to object files directly and not in archive format?